# Fargate node failed to be autoscaled by VPA

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

I am currently trying to use VPA for my AWS EKS fargate application, after all the config has been set up, the fargate pod failed to autoscale. Does anyone know what I have done wrong?

Btw, I deployed core-dns, metrics-server, vpa-admission-controller, vpa-recommender, vpa-updater using NodeGroup(ec2 instance), while vpa-test was deployed to fargate. It is a possible problem for this?

Thank you.

my deploy.yaml file

```
apiVersion: "autoscaling.k8s.io/v1"
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: vpa
  namespace: k8s-fargate
spec: 
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: vpa-test
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
  resourcePolicy: 
    containerPolicies:
      - containerName: jboss-api
        minAllowed:
          cpu: 200m
        maxAllowed:
          cpu: 1
        controlledResources: ["cpu"]

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: k8s-fargate
  name: vpa-test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vpa-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vpa-test
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: properties
          configMap: 
            name: properties
      containers:
        - name: jboss-api
          image: amazonaws.com/imageName:1.1.3
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args:
            - "-c"
            - "while true; do timeout 15s yes >/dev/null; done"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8443
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
            limits:
              memory: "2500Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: properties
              mountPath: "/path/"
              readOnly: false
```

result for `kubectl describe pod podName`:

```
Name:                 vpa-test-79c9fc869f-p8tm9
Namespace:            k8s-fargate
Priority:             2000001000
Priority Class Name:  system-node-critical
Node:                 fargate-ip-10-0-128-246.compute.internal/10.0.128.246
Start Time:           Wed, 10 Aug 2022 16:47:50 +0800
Labels:               app=vpa-test
                      eks.amazonaws.com/fargate-profile=k8s-fargate
                      pod-template-hash=79c9fc869f
Annotations:          CapacityProvisioned: 0.25vCPU 2GB
                      Logging: LoggingDisabled: LOGGING_CONFIGMAP_NOT_FOUND
                      kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
                      vpaObservedContainers: jboss-api
                      vpaUpdates: Pod resources updated by vpa: container 0: cpu request, cpu limit
Status:               Running
IP:                   10.0.128.246
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.128.246
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/vpa-test-79c9fc869f
Containers:
  jboss-api:

    Image:         dkr.ecr.amazonaws.com/api:1.1.3

    Port:          8443/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Command:
      /bin/sh
    Args:
      -c
      while true; do timeout 15s yes >/dev/null; done
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 10 Aug 2022 16:48:25 +0800
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1355m
      memory:  2500Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        271m
      memory:     1Gi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /usr/local (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-bts2q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  ica-co1-properties:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      properties
    Optional:  false
  kube-api-access-bts2q:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason           Age    From               Message
  ----     ------           ----   ----               -------
  Warning  LoggingDisabled  2m38s  fargate-scheduler  Disabled logging because aws-logging configmap was not found. configmap "aws-logging" not found
  Normal   Scheduled        105s   fargate-scheduler  Successfully assigned k8s-fargate/vpa-test-79c9fc869f-p8tm9 to fargate-ip-10-0-128-246.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulling          104s   kubelet            Pulling image "dkr.ecr.amazonaws.com/api:1.1.3"
  Normal   Pulled           71s    kubelet            Successfully pulled image "dkr.ecr.amazonaws.com/api:1.1.3" in 33.012615032s
  Normal   Created          70s    kubelet            Created container jboss-api
  Normal   Started          70s    kubelet            Started container jboss-api
```

`kubectl describe vpa`:

```
Name:         vpa
Namespace:    k8s-fargate
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1        
Kind:         VerticalPodAutoscaler        
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-08-10T08:45:53Z
  Generation:          4
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1    
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:resourcePolicy:
          .:
          f:containerPolicies:
        f:targetRef:
          .:
          f:apiVersion:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
        f:updatePolicy:
          .:
          f:updateMode:
    Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-08-10T08:45:53Z
    API Version:  autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:recommendation:
          .:
          f:containerRecommendations:
    Manager:         recommender
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-08-10T08:45:59Z
  Resource Version:  112490
Spec:
  Resource Policy:
    Container Policies:
      Container Name:  jboss-api
      Controlled Resources:
        cpu
      Max Allowed:
        Cpu:  1
      Min Allowed:
        Cpu:  200m
  Target Ref:
    API Version:  apps/v1
    Kind:         Deployment
    Name:         vpa-test
  Update Policy:
    Update Mode:  Auto
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-08-10T08:45:59Z
    Status:                True
    Type:                  RecommendationProvided
  Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  jboss-api
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:  267m
      Target:
        Cpu:  271m
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:  271m
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:  1
Events:       <none>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pod has been assigned with 0.5vCPU (500m) and the recommendation (271m) is way below. Try stress your pod with `while :; do yes > /dev/null; done`

Comment: thank you. I have redone all the deployment and config, assigned the pod with 0.25vCPU and make the node reached 250vCPU. But still no action for VPA.

Comment: Status of vpa as below:

Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-08-10T09:56:32Z
    Status:                True
    Type:                  RecommendationProvided
  Recommendation:
    Container Recommendations:
      Container Name:  jboss-api
      Lower Bound:
        Cpu:  200m
      Target:
        Cpu:  271m
      Uncapped Target:
        Cpu:  271m
      Upper Bound:
        Cpu:  1
Events:       <none>

Comment: VPA needs replicas of 2 to scale, can you try `kubectl scale deploy vpa-test --namespace vpa-test --replicas=2`?

Comment: yes, you are right, it does need 2 pods to do this. Thank you so much!